# Add to array after button is pressed with session array

Tags: php, arrays

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>13.15</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="post">
         fruit: <input type="text" name="fruit"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="add" value="add"><br><br>
         -------------------------<br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="sort" value="sort"> <input type="submit" name="shuffle" value="'shuffle'"><br><br>
         -------------------------
         <br><br>
      </form>
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['fruit'])) $_SESSION['fruit'] = array("Pear", "Apple", "Orange");

$fruit = $_SESSION['fruit'];

if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    array_push($fruit, $_POST['fruit']);
    $_SESSION['fruit'] = $fruit;
} 

if(isset($_POST['sort']))
{
sort($fruit);
foreach ($fruit as $key => $val) {
    echo "- " .  $val . "<br />" . "\n";
}
}

if(isset($_POST['shuffle']))
{
shuffle($fruit);
foreach ($fruit as $key => $val) {
    echo "- " .  $val . "<br />" . "\n";
}
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make it so that when I type in a fruit in a input field and press a button, it will be pushed to the array, to make this work, I tried using sessions. Unfortunately it is not working, the above is what I have tried

Comment: `$fruit` isn't `defined` for the `$_SESSION['fruit']`

Comment: Could you edit my code for a working example? I haven't used sessions before and this is what I tried after reading about it

Comment: What you were trying to do is use `$fruit` as `$_SESSION['fruit']` but it will not work with that kind of assignment because they are 2 different variables and the value is passed from one to the other. you could use a reference or do all processing on `$fruit` and reassign it to `$_SESSION` at the end of your script

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Detect when the session variable does not yet exist and then initialise it
- Save any changes back to the session variable before ending the script

Here is the suggested code for that:

```
session_start();

// first time initialisation
if (!isset($_SESSION['fruit'])) $_SESSION['fruit'] = array("Pear", "Apple", "Orange");

// get current list from session
$fruit = $_SESSION['fruit'];

// add new fruit if provided, and update session variable as well
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    array_push($fruit, $_POST['fruit']);
    $_SESSION['fruit'] = $fruit;
}
```

Now make sure you output the new list in the browser. So move that outputting code out of the `if` blocks, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
    sort($fruit);
}

if(isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($fruit);
}
// Always output
foreach ($fruit as $key => $val) {
    echo "- " .  $val . "<br />" . "\n";
}
```

This is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>13.15</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="post">
         fruit: <input type="text" name="fruit"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="add" value="add"><br><br>
         -------------------------<br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="sort" value="sort"> 
         <input type="submit" name="shuffle" value="'shuffle'"><br><br>
         -------------------------
         <br><br>
      </form>
<?php

session_start();

// first time initialisation
if (!isset($_SESSION['fruit'])) $_SESSION['fruit'] = array("Pear", "Apple", "Orange");

// get current list from session
$fruit = $_SESSION['fruit'];

// add new fruit if provided, and update session variable as well
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    array_push($fruit, $_POST['fruit']);
    $_SESSION['fruit'] = $fruit;
} 

if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
    sort($fruit);
}

if(isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($fruit);
}
// Always output
foreach ($fruit as $key => $val) {
    echo "- " .  $val . "<br />" . "\n";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited the code with your answer but it does not seem to work, I can not add new fruits to the array

Comment: The reason is that you must also output the list of fruit. Since you want that to happen always, don't put that part of the code inside an `if`, but only once at the very end of the script. See addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, the only problem now is that I can only add one item to the array and when I sort or shuffle, the original array is shown

Comment: There must be something you did not do as in my answer, because I have it running correctly on my pc: can add one fruit after the other, shuffle, sort, and the list will keep the additional items. Please check.

Comment: Posted. If this does not work for you, there must be something wrong with the PHP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$output='';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['fruits'])){
    $fruits=unserialize(stripslashes($_SESSION['fruits']));
    if (!is_array($fruits)) {
        // something went WRONG - initialize to custom array
        $fruits = array("Pear", "Apple", "Orange");
    }
}//at this point you have the last session to an array

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $txt=$_POST['fruit'];
    if(!empty($txt)) array_push($fruits, $txt);
}

if(isset($_POST['sort']))
{
sort($fruits);

}

if(isset($_POST['shuffle']))
{
shuffle($fruits);

}

/*at this point even add/sort or shuffle the final
array you should store it for the next session*/
if(isset($fruits)){
    $_SESSION['fruits']=serialize($fruits);

    /* you should center here an content for later output*/
    foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
        $output.= "- " .  $val . "<br />" . "\n";
    }
}
/* 
you should NOT send content when you store sessions cookies
see? no blank or chars here-> <?php
neither ->X  ?>X<!DOCTYPE html>
|
|
__     */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>13.15</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="post">
         fruit: <input type="text" name="fruit"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="add" value="add"><br><br>
         -------------------------<br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="sort" value="sort"> <input type="submit" name="shuffle" value="'shuffle'"><br><br>
         -------------------------
         <br><br>
      </form>
<?php

echo($output);
phpinfo();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use `$fruit` as if it were `$_SESSION['fruit']`
To do such you would have to use a reference
With the kind of assignment you are doing, the value is simply being passed from one variable into the other

for example

```
$a = 4;
$b = $a;
$b = 5;

// $a =4, $b = 5
```

the value 4 is simply passed from `$a` to `$b` and any changes in `$b` are not reflected in `$a` because they are 2 separate variables

On the other hand if you use a reference you are essentially giving the variable another name and changes will be reflected

```
$a = 4;
$b = &$a;
$b = 5;

// $a = 5, $b = 5
```

for your code it can result into something like

```
<?php

session_start();
$fruit = &$_SESSION['fruit'];

if (!isset($fruit)) 
    $fruit = array("Pear", "Apple", "Orange");

//...
```